# Python Connect four Diagonal Checking

Tags: python

I'm having issue getting my code started. I have a Connect 4 project for my programming class and I'm having a really stupid issue. I don't understand the diagonal checking. He gave us an example but I honestly don't get it.

```
def CheckForWinner(board, playerName, playerChar):


diagonal = board[2][0] + board[3][1] + board[4][2] + board[5][3]
if playerChar * 4 in diagonal:
    return playerName
```

It is a 42 space board(7x6)

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
```

I'm just having difficulties under standing what it is checking. I'm not asking for you to give me the code. Just an explanation please. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's building a string up of the characters stored in a diagonal. For example, if the board is:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|_|A|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|B|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|C|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|D|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
```

Then the following line:

```
diagonal = board[2][0] + board[3][1] + board[4][2] + board[5][3]
```

will assign the value `ABCD` to the variable `diagonal`, because it's concatenating the characters in `board[2][0]` (`A`), `board[3][1]` (`B`), etc... into one string: `ABCD`.

The `if` statement makes up a 4-character string of the player's character, and checks if it is in the `diagonal` string. If the player's character is `X`, for example, then the `if` evaluates to checking if `XXXX` is in `ABCD`. It will then return the player's name if this is `True`, which means they've won.

(Of course, the actual location of the A, B, C and D in my example depends on what way round the list of lists is representing the board)

Comment: I feel really stupid for not seeing this now. I warned him I had never played this game before so I guess I just didn't understand why it was checking diagonally. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|W|_|_|
|_|_|_|Z|_|_|_|
|_|_|Y|_|_|_|_|
|_|X|_|_|_|_|_|

x = 2,0
y = 3,1
z = 4,2
w = 5,3
```

it is probably using 1 for player 1 and 2 for player 2 so the board would look like this as an array (note that the array is probably (row) inverted from the displayed grid.)

```
player = 2
the_board = [[0,0,2,0,0,0,0],  
             [0,0,0,2,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,2,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,2,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
print the_board[2][0]  #2
diagonal = the_board[2][0] + the_board[3][1] + the_board[4][2] + the_board[5][3] # 2+2+2+2 = 8
player * 4  == diagonal # 2*4 =?= 2+2+2+2
```

Comment: Some text to explain the board/conditon check would make this a lot more comprehensible to the OP

Comment: I was adding it but I had some actual work pop up in the intermin